# How to convert a Class Library project to a Web Application project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, class-library

Long story short, because of some issues with architecture and the fact that someone already put a few .aspx files in a class library, I'd like to just finish off the change and convert a class library to a web application.  This is using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0.  Is there an easy way of doing this?  Thanks!

EDIT: I was hoping for a better method than recreating the project, I had too many issues with broken references when I tried just creating a new project, including one I could never seem to fix.

Comment: "class librarry", arrr! Hope ye didn't pirate that code! Arr! Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a new web application project in your solution and drag and drop all files from class library  to the new web application project.

Comment: was hoping for an easy way to modify the project files directly but I think this will be the only way.

Comment: There are other solutions are, **but** they take longer time;)

Answer (score 99):

I did this by hand today in Visual Studio 2005 because it seemed easier and faster than the above. I just diffed a working web application .csproj file with my class library to determine the relevant differences. Based on that, I made the following changes. Keep in mind that it may be different for other versions or your individual project.

1) Right after the `<ProjectGuid>` element near the top, I added

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

2) I removed `<ProjectType>Local</ProjectType>`
3) At the bottom of the file, right before the closing `</Project>`, I added

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v8.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
      <ProjectExtensions>
        <VisualStudio>
          <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
            <WebProjectProperties>
              <UseIIS>False</UseIIS>
              <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
              <DevelopmentServerPort>3291</DevelopmentServerPort>
              <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
              <IISUrl>
              </IISUrl>
              <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
            </WebProjectProperties>
          </FlavorProperties>
        </VisualStudio>
</ProjectExtensions>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as it actually answers the question while the selected answer is a work-around... and it does not take a long time to add these to the proj file.

Comment: Works on VS 2012.  I used this for <ProjectTypeGuids>:  
  
`<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>`

Comment: Took me 10 seconds to do this after I set up my diff tool.  This is way faster than creating a new project, copying files and then having to debug all the stuff that doesn't work.

Comment: Worked for me in VS 2013 but watch the GUIDs.  I had a .vbproj and was getting "Project with that name already opened in the solution."  Turns out that for VB projects, you need to use {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F} instead of {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}.  A list of Project Type GUIDs and their meanings is [here](http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx).

Comment: VS2012 didn't have the "<ProjectType>Local</ProjectType>".   In addition to ProjectExtensions section, I saw (and added)  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />    But this was great to show what the tiny diffs were.  I can start/debug my webapplication now.

Comment: I was doing it the other way around, but the advice (in reverse) worked just as well for turning a web app into a class library.

Comment: For VS 2015 do not add <Import>...</Import>. After <TargetFrameworkVersion> add <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>

Comment: @JamesQMurphy Realizing your comment is from 2014, that 404s now. [Here's a contemporary (to your 2014 comment) archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20140708152358/http://www.mztools.com/Articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx) but here's also [the latest version Archive.org has before 404](https://web.archive.org/web/20210615194319/https://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008017.aspx) where it looks like the author had added some new GUIDs over the years. Thanks!

Comment: @ruffin and thank you!  Shame I can't edit my comment from ten years ago.  I'd also put `code` tags around those GUIDs... I was such a noob back then.

Answer (score 16):

It's mentioned in the comments already, but somehow it's easy to miss (at least I missed it). If you applied Brad's solution, but your project is still missing the option to add areas, controllers and views, you still need to add an MVC project guid `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}`.

The `ProjectTypeGuids` line should now look like this:

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

As mentioned by JamesQMurphy, `{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}` will not work in VB projects. That's because it's a C# project guid. So for VB project a VB project guid has to be used. This guid is `{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}`.

Here is a list of some of the known project guids (taken from [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Reference/720512/List-of-Visual-Studio-Project-Type-GUIDs)):

- ASP.NET MVC 1.0  {603C0E0B-DB56-11DC-BE95-000D561079B0}
- ASP.NET MVC 2.0  {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}
- ASP.NET MVC 3.0  {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}
- ASP.NET MVC 4.0  {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47
- **C#     {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}**
- C++  {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
- Database     {A9ACE9BB-CECE-4E62-9AA4-C7E7C5BD2124}
- Database (other project types)   {4F174C21-8C12-11D0-8340-0000F80270F8}
- Deployment Cab   {3EA9E505-35AC-4774-B492-AD1749C4943A}
- Deployment Merge Module  {06A35CCD-C46D-44D5-987B-CF40FF872267}
- Deployment Setup     {978C614F-708E-4E1A-B201-565925725DBA}
- Deployment Smart Device Cab  {AB322303-2255-48EF-A496-5904EB18DA55}
- Distributed System   {F135691A-BF7E-435D-8960-F99683D2D49C}
- F#   {F2A71F9B-5D33-465A-A702-920D77279786}
- J#   {E6FDF86B-F3D1-11D4-8576-0002A516ECE8}
- Legacy (2003) Smart Device (C#)  {20D4826A-C6FA-45DB-90F4-C717570B9F32}
- Legacy (2003) Smart Device (VB.NET)  {CB4CE8C6-1BDB-4DC7-A4D3-65A1999772F8}
- **Model-View-Controller v2 (MVC2)    {F85E285D-A4E0-4152-9332-AB1D724D3325}**
- **Model-View-Controller v3 (MVC3)    {E53F8FEA-EAE0-44A6-8774-FFD645390401}**
- **Model-View-Controller v4 (MVC4)    {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}**
- Mono for Android     {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF}
- MonoTouch    {6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B}
- MonoTouch Binding    {F5B4F3BC-B597-4E2B-B552-EF5D8A32436F}
- Portable Class Library   {786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB}
- SharePoint (C#)  {593B0543-81F6-4436-BA1E-4747859CAAE2}
- SharePoint (VB.NET)  {EC05E597-79D4-47f3-ADA0-324C4F7C7484}
- SharePoint Workflow  {F8810EC1-6754-47FC-A15F-DFABD2E3FA90}
- Silverlight  {A1591282-1198-4647-A2B1-27E5FF5F6F3B}
- Smart Device (C#)    {4D628B5B-2FBC-4AA6-8C16-197242AEB884}
- Smart Device (VB.NET)    {68B1623D-7FB9-47D8-8664-7ECEA3297D4F}
- Solution Folder  {2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}
- Test     {3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB}
- **VB.NET     {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}**
- Visual Database Tools    {C252FEB5-A946-4202-B1D4-9916A0590387}
- Visual Studio Tools for Applications (VSTA)  {A860303F-1F3F-4691-B57E-529FC101A107}
- Visual Studio Tools for Office (VSTO)    {BAA0C2D2-18E2-41B9-852F-F413020CAA33}
- Web Application  {349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21}
- Web Site     {E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}
- Windows (C#)     {FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}
- Windows (VB.NET)     {F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}
- Windows (Visual C++)     {8BC9CEB8-8B4A-11D0-8D11-00A0C91BC942}
- Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)   {3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}
- Windows Phone 8/8.1 Blank/Hub/Webview App    {76F1466A-8B6D-4E39-A767-685A06062A39}
- Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (C#)     {C089C8C0-30E0-4E22-80C0-CE093F111A43}
- Windows Phone 8/8.1 App (VB.NET)     {DB03555F-0C8B-43BE-9FF9-57896B3C5E56}
- Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)    {60DC8134-EBA5-43B8-BCC9-BB4BC16C2548}
- Windows Store (Metro) Apps & Components  {BC8A1FFA-BEE3-4634-8014-F334798102B3}
- Workflow (C#)    {14822709-B5A1-4724-98CA-57A101D1B079}
- Workflow (VB.NET)    {D59BE175-2ED0-4C54-BE3D-CDAA9F3214C8}
- Workflow Foundation  {32F31D43-81CC-4C15-9DE6-3FC5453562B6}
- Xamarin.Android  {EFBA0AD7-5A72-4C68-AF49-83D382785DCF}
- Xamarin.iOS  {6BC8ED88-2882-458C-8E55-DFD12B67127B}
- XNA (Windows)    {6D335F3A-9D43-41b4-9D22-F6F17C4BE596}
- XNA (XBox)   {2DF5C3F4-5A5F-47a9-8E94-23B4456F55E2}
- XNA (Zune)   {D399B71A-8929-442a-A9AC-8BEC78BB2433}

P.S. In case you wonder, the list is apparently public domain.

Answer (score 1):

in .net core 3.1 modify the project file [project name].csproj and change

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

to

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
```

now save changes and reload the project, now you have a web app (MVC) project.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easiest to just create a new web project, then copy over the class files and *.aspx files into the new web project?

Comment: I actually attempted that but had a pile of broken references I couldn't fix as a result, I suppose I could try again....