# Why does this simple owin middleware cause a 403.14

Tags: c#, iis, owin

I'm just dipping into creating some custom middleware for owin, but when I run it, it's showing a 403.14 in the browser.

I created an empty WebProject, added an owin startup class like below

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(OwinTest.Startup))]
namespace OwinTest {

    public class Startup {

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.Use<MySimpleMiddleware>();
        }

        class MySimpleMiddleware : OwinMiddleware {

            public MySimpleMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next) : base(next) { }

            public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context) {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("Hello, world.");

                return base.Next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which, when run in either IIS express (8), or IIS (7.5), it provides me with a `HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.` error.

**However**, if I change the final line of `Invoke` to be `return Task.FromResult(0);`, then it works as expected, but I don't know if I necessarily want to be terminating the pipeline at this point (or do I, if this is the `primary` middleware?)

Comment: I found this SO post useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204884/2638872

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this into `void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)`

```
          app.Run(
            context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("More Hello, World");
            });
```

Observe the simple illustration of the the pipeline [here](http://blog.tomasjansson.com/owin-middleware/)

[image]

It doesn't seem that you can have just middleware and no website. return Task.FromResult(0) works because now your middleware has taken the role of the app, ignoring next and returning.