# Where is IApplicationBuilder.UseJwtBearerAuthentication extension in ASP.net 5?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've seen examples that that indicate `IApplicationBuilder` has an extension method `.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(Action<?> options)`.

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32581491/mvc-6-vs-mvc-5-bearerauthentication-in-web-api) and [AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server
 sample server startup file](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server/blob/vNext/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Server/Startup.cs) seem to say that there is such an extension. On the OpenIdConnect, I looked at the extensions folder and I don't see an extension named UseJwtBearerAuthentication. Even [this blog](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/07/22/the-state-of-security-in-asp-net-5-and-mvc-6-oauth-2-0-openid-connect-and-identityserver/) says that it's supposed to be included with ASP.net 5. I also tried adding Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuthBearer, 1.0.0-beta3 to my project.json and reference it in Startup.cs. No help.

The only thing I have different is that I'm using -beta7, but I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your runtime version. In beta7 the package is called [Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.**OAuthBearer**](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/1.0.0-beta7/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer), while in beta 8 the package is renamed to [Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.**JwtBearer**](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer).

Since you are using beta7, add this to your project.json:

```
"Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OAuthBearer": "1.0.0-beta7"
```

Pro-tip: never mix beta versions like beta3 security packages and beta7 MVC packages.

Comment: I'm getting Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.JwtBearer >= 1.0.0-beta7 could not be resolved.

Comment: @MickaelCaruso sorry, I overlooked that. I've updated my post.

Comment: Thank you. I saw *.OAuthBearer in project.json Intellisense, so that might be it. It's good to know, though, that *.JwtBearer is what it should be in beta8.

Answer (score 1):

In RC2, there are

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth
```