# Configuration(IAppBuilder) not firing on start up

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

The configuration method below doesn't get fired.

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(SCM.Web.Startup))]
namespace SCM.Web
{
  public partial class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder) { }
  }
}
```

I've followed all the hints from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203982/owinstartup-not-firing) and it's a new project, not an upgrade. I can't for my life see how to get it to stop on the breakpoint and I'm in need to get more suggestions on how to troubleshoot it.

It's an intranet application so there's no logging in. The identity gets set to the Windows credentials, instead. I need to assign the roles so that only certain users can access certain actions in the controllers. I'm usually applying OWIN and application cookies, so that's the method I'm trying to follow here, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running the website on an external IIS or maybe on the "real" IIS installed on your computer (and not the one that is fired up when you start the run), then it's likely that you're missing the breakpoint because the debugger isn't attached to the process yet when you pass by.

I think that you can confirm it by either checking the settings of your solution and projects or simply adding this code to the method that you don't think that you pass through.

```
throw new Exception("Killroy was here...");
```

Answer (score 3):

You need an [`OwinStartup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.owinstartupattribute(v=vs.113).aspx) attribute to tell Owin what method to call. From the docs:

> Used to mark which class in an assembly should be used for automatic startup.

Add one to your project, before the namespace declaration:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Your.Namespace.Startup))]
namespace Your.Namespace
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
      public void Configuration(IAppBuilder builder) { }
    }
}
```

There are some other methods to let Owin know which method ([described here](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection)) but this is the simplest and probably the most common.

Comment: I'm sorry but I realize that I was providing insufficient information. I didn't realize it was of significance and trying to create the minimal, representative example, I cut off more than I should. Please accept my apology for that. I've updated the question.

Comment: You don't have an app setting for `owin:appStartup` by any chance?

Comment: Nope, as far I could tell there's no such string anywhere in the solution. I'll recheck tomorrow at work, though, just to make sure. That element come in when upgrading from MVC 4, right? My case is a clean MVC 5. Just in case I've missed it first time I checked - what do I do with it? Remove?