# Add a Startup.cs file in MVC5 project without authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I bind the startup.cs file adding manually to the project?
I created it from `Add > New Item > OWIN Startup class` but is ignored by the app.

The Startup class

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebApplication1.Startup))]

namespace WebTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

**Update**

I can do it thanks to this

[OwinStartup not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203982/owinstartup-not-firing)

Comment: In what way is it ignored? Have you put a breakpoint in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(**WebApplication1**.Startup))]
```

In the OwinStartup attribute you specify a class `WebApplication1.Startup` but the class shown says `WebTest.Startup`

Comment: Sorry I did not copy the right code, but is like you said, anyway is not working. Do I have to configure something in the web.config file?